# Powershell equivalent to Python "in"?

Tags: python, arrays, powershell, syntax

I've been using arrays lately and really missing Python's "in" operator.

e.g.:

```
if ("hello" in ["hello", "there", "sup"]):
    print "this prints :)"
```

I've made up for it a little bit by creating a "ThereExists-Object" function, like so:

```
function ThereExists-Object([System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock] $sb)
{
    return ($input | where $sb) -as [bool]
}
New-Alias -Name ThereExists -Value ThereExists-Object
```

e.g.:

```
if ($arrayOfStuff | thereexists { $_ -eq "hello" } )
{
    write-host "this prints too"
}
```

obviously I could define another function for this as well... but I'd like to know if there's some syntactical sugar that I'm unfamiliar with that could get this job done.

So... is there any?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$arrColors = "blue", "red", "green", "yellow", "white", "pink", "orange", "turquoise"
$arrColors -contains "black" 
False
$arrColors -contains "blue"
True
```

source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692798.aspx

Comment: ha thanks... i must not have picked the right keywords in my googling somehow

Answer (score 3):

From Powershell v3.0 onwards you can use the `-in` operator itself:

```
PS> "hello" -in "hello", "there", "sup"
True
PS> "hell" -in "hello", "there", "sup"
False
```

Comment: hmm that's cool... i suppose... except it seems redundant. Are they simply the same operator with swapped arguments?

Comment: @Nacht - I would say they are bringing in operators found and commonly used in other languages